# C# Timer not firing information

Tags: c#, timer

I have two timers in my c# application. However one of the timers do not work. 
Here is the code that I have used for my timers:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 600000;
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(call1);
timer.Start();

System.Timers.Timer alerttimer= new System.Timers.Timer();
alerttimer.Interval = 600000; 
alerttimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(call2);
alerttimer.Start();
```

This is exactly the way I have it in my project, one timer after the other. The first timer executes the event, but the other one does not. 
**Am I missing something that do not allow both timers to work?**
Thank you.

EDIT: Here is an extract from my methods, there is more, but all they do is get ram, cpu, drive and services information.

```
 public static void call1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {

        PerformanceCounter ramCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        PerformanceCounter cpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to view other information...\n");
        Console.WriteLine("CPU and RAM information");

        double perf = cpuCount.NextValue();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        perf = cpuCount.NextValue();
        Console.WriteLine("CPU Performance: " + perf + " %");
        ServerStats.cpuLoad = perf;
    }

   public static void call2(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            PerformanceCounter ramAlert = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

            double ram1, ram2, ram3, ram4, ram5, ram6, ram7, ram8, ram9, ram0;
            ram0 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram1 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram2 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram3 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram4 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram5 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram6 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram7 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram8 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            ram9 = ramAlert.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(50000);

            double total = ram0 + ram1 + ram2 + ram3 + ram4 + ram5 + ram6 + ram7 + ram8 + ram9;
            double average = total / 10;

            if (average >= 90)
            {
                string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

                Alert.serverName = hostName;
                Alert.alertType = "RAM alert: " + average;
            }
```

Comment: Are you sample correct? timer2 is never started.. alerttimer is started in the code you provided.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I have alerttimer in my code.

Comment: How looks you call1 and call2 methods?

Comment: may be because of the code in method `call1`, can you add that code too?

Comment: Do you want an event to occur every time the interval occurs, because you should use "Timer.Tick" event for this.

Comment: @Rariolu, yes, I'd like the call1 and call2 to happen every 10 minutes.

Comment: @avantvous: Doesn't it fire at all? Did you put a breakpoint at the beggining of Call2 and see?

Comment: @CharithJ, the first timer fires information, the second one does not.

Comment: Do you need to do the second task from a timer? To me you're doing work that will take at least `500000ms` anyway. You could simply have two loops, the first round getting all the values and the second around getting the values in `RAM`, will cut down on code and will mean that you wouldn't have to rely on a `Timer`, although you'd want to start this in a long running `Task`.

Comment: @StephenRoss I will try that, but I need the timers to send the information to the database every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what the problem was. Firstly there was a delay in posting call2, because of `Thread.Sleep(50000)` which is used to calculate the average for ram. So basically, the timer was firing, but after a substantial delay.

Secondly, this program is a service therefore I have to change my version and product code in Service Properties to prevent Visual Studio from running an older version.

Thanks all for your help.